# Google Service Account Token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I prepared all of prompts for Vertex AI. It all ready to go. However, I have one main issue.

I need to make request to Vertex AI in my backend. However token codes in the examples expires after 1 hour.

After lot's of chats with Bards and spending 5+ hours about service accounts, API keys, I couldn't find a way to get access token from Google Developer Console.

I make requests to my own project. There would not be "user-login".

How should I do that?

Comment: scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'

authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
json_key_io: File.open('PATH-TO-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-JSON-FILE'),
scope: scope)

response = authorizer.fetch_access_token!

response["access_token"]

Comment: This solve the issue for those who're seeking answer.

Comment: Post an answer with details on your solution instead of a comment that is difficult to read.

Answer (score -3):

To authenticate your requests to Vertex AI from your backend without relying on user-login, you can make use of a service account and obtain a long-lived access token. Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Create a service account:

   - Go to the Google Cloud Console (console.cloud.google.com) and navigate to your project.
   - Open the IAM & Admin section and select "Service Accounts."
   - Click on "Create Service Account" and provide a name and optional description for the account.
   - Assign the necessary roles/permissions to the service account based on the actions it needs to perform in Vertex AI.
   - Choose the key type (JSON or P12) and click "Create" to generate the service account.
2. Obtain an access token:

   - If you chose the JSON key type, you will receive a JSON key file. Store this file securely on your backend server.
   - In your backend code, load the JSON key file and use it to authenticate your requests. The exact process depends on the programming language and libraries you are using.
   - Typically, you'll need to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path of the JSON key file.
   - With the credentials set up correctly, you can use the Google Cloud SDK or the client libraries for your preferred language to obtain an access token programmatically. The token will have a longer expiration time (usually around 1 hour) compared to the short-lived tokens you encountered previously.
3. Refresh the access token:

   - Once you have obtained the initial access token, you can store it securely in your backend.
   - Before making a request to Vertex AI, check if the token has expired.
   - If the token has expired, use the refresh token (included in the JSON key file) or the service account private key to obtain a new access token programmatically.

By following these steps, you can authenticate your requests to Vertex AI from your backend using a service account and obtain a long-lived access token, avoiding the need for frequent token refreshes.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Google OAuth tokens are short-lived, except for a Google Cloud Organization which can create tokens for 12 hours (with proper configuration). This answer mixes details from user and service account authorization steps, which again is wrong and misleading. Service accounts do not provide refresh tokens. When a token expires a new token must be created.

Comment: I try everything here. Bard return very similar ideas. Issue is I'm using Ruby and it's impossible to understand Ruby library to find a way to authenticate...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).